# Can a ListView have two or more different types of row layouts in Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-listview

I have a very simple ListView right now in a ListActivity that displays just a list of text values. Here's my current code:

```
public class InfoActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
        // loads up the values array here
        // ...

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

My XML file for InfoActivity has nothing in it because I am using a ListActivity.

What I want to do it make custom layouts for the rows. The first 5 rows will have layoutA.xml and the second 5 rows will have layoutB.xml.

How do I do this? I'm lost on where to begin. Obviously I'm looking for the simplest code possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layout-for-each-row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy enough, you simply need to extends ArrayAdapter. My ArrayAdapter does two things differently:

- instead of passing one ResourceId, my adapter take an array of ResourceIds
- getView() checks the position and loads the appropriate resource

This is a trivial example. If you plan on making it more complex than the first half looks one way and the second half is different, then you should override [getViewTypeCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getViewTypeCount%28%29) and [getItemViewType()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29).

Working example:

```
public class Example extends Activity {
    public class MyArrayAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> {
        LayoutInflater mInflater;
        int[] mLayoutResourceIds;

        public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int[] textViewResourceId, List<T> objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId[0], objects);
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            mLayoutResourceIds = textViewResourceId;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null && position > 2)
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(mLayoutResourceIds[1], parent, false);
            return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String[] array = new String[] {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"};
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        Collections.addAll(list, array);

        ListView listView = new ListView(this);
        listView.setAdapter(new MyArrayAdapter<String>(this, new int[] {android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice}, list));
        setContentView(listView);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a great blog post about having different layout for your list items.

[handling-listviews-with-multiple-row-types](http://logc.at/2011/10/10/handling-listviews-with-multiple-row-types/)

There is also the sample project so you can configure and try the example.

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you have a counter, say starting at 0, and then Inflate and reuse the first five with `layoutA.xml`, then when its at 5, scrap the inflated `layoutA.xml` with `layoutB.xml`. That should be simple enough to do. Of course, I am talking about this through `BaseAdapter`, which allows you to make an Adapter that sets each row in the `ListView`. I've never actually used `ListActivity`. But the process should be the same.

Just to add on what @lxx posted, the link I mean, it definitely helps you figure out how to accomplish what you want. Though I will say its overkill in my opinion to use those methods when you want 5 of one kind, and 5 of another. Definitely use that link as a good baseline, but just use a counter. Its simpler. In terms of memory, only re-inflate the layout when you know the counter has already put in 5 Views. That way you aren't doing it everytime.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use MergeAdapter (cwac-merge), where in one ListView you can have multiple Adapters with different layouts.

Answer (score 0):

If we need to show different type of view in list-view then its good to use getViewTypeCount() and getItemViewType() in adapter instead of toggling a view VIEW.GONE and VIEW.VISIBLE can be very expensive task inside getView() which will affect the list scroll.

Please check this one for use of getViewTypeCount() and getItemViewType() in Adapter.

Link :  [the-use-of-getviewtypecount](http://kyogs.blogspot.in/2014/06/the-use-of-getviewtypecount-and.html)